# Number of zeros of an entire function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, analytic-functions

Let $f$ be an entire function then my question is: a formula to find the number of zeros of $f$ on the line $\Re(s)=1,0<\Im(s)<h$ where $h>0$.

I was thinking of applying the argument principle to the rectangle $1-\epsilon\leq \Re(s)\leq 1+\epsilon   ,0<\Im(s)<h $ where $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrarily small and $N_\epsilon(h)$ is the number of zeros in the rectangle upto height $h$.

At last we take $\epsilon\to 0^+$.

Is this method correct or any other method please?

Comment: If we call the integral around the rectangle $a(\epsilon)$, note that $a$ is a discrete-valued function. This makes taking the limit kind of weird.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I am calling the integral around the rectangle $a_\epsilon(h)$ which gives the number of zeros upto height $h$ and then at last we take $\epsilon\to 0^+$. Is this correct?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I mistakenly wrote that $h$ is fixed. $h$ is not fixed

Comment: In general there is no simple way to prove that a zero is exactly on $\Re(s)=1$ and not just very close to it, so yes you'll need to look at $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\partial |\Re(s)-1|<\epsilon,\Im(s)\in (0,h)} f'(z)/f(z)dz$

Comment: @reuns Thank you for the hint. Can you please explain what do you mean by $\partial|\Re(s)-1|<\epsilon$?

Comment: @reuns I would be obliged if you write a short answer of your comment.